# jqplot - how to draw bar chart

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I downloaded jqplot and integrated it in my site. everything works fine. But I am having problem drawing bar chart. It only shows line chart..

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var s1 = [[1,male], [2,female], [3,other]];
var ticks = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
    // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

my result is (the middle one)- but I want a bar chart .
[image]

Comment: even the code for bar chart is drawing line chart.. am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include barRenderer plugin :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>`

(Either in his minify version or full one.)

Answer (score 0):

See here for demo

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1629/)

Include `jqplot.barRenderer` plugin in the header

Change the code like the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var s1 = [[1,'male'], [2,'female'], [3,'other']];
var ticks = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
    // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..

    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        },
         yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer

        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true
    }


  });
      });
```